# Is Were or Was the correct preposition for 3rd person singular "my heart"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, usage

I understand that if I refer to my heart (my leg, my hair, etc.), it is third person singular and so I should use "WAS", but there's a song called "If my heart WERE a ball" that brought this question to me. Is there a difference on its use or is this a mistake?

Comment: Google "subjunctive mood" :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a special form of "to be" used in counterfactual clauses. That is when what you are saying isn't true: my heart is not a ball.
Here is a reference to that use:
[Wikipedia "use of the past subjunctive"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive)
"The main use of the past subjunctive form, ***were***, which is also known as the *irrealis* is in counterfactual *if* clauses."

Another reference discusses the form extensively:
[Thoughtco "past subjunctive"](https://www.thoughtco.com/past-subjunctive-1691490)

In ordinary speech, in your example sentence, some people will use the form "was".

Comment: Thank you for answer, now I know something else. So, regarding on that, another song called "If my heart WAS a house" is mistakenly written? Here are the links to both songs, so you can see I'm not joking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOcB-1QfpuM - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKYzqA2Vgco

Comment: Note the last sentence of my answer. It's common for people to use "was" in that situation. I wouldn't call it mistaken, it's just language changing.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that. I was reading your linked page and found this phrase to explain that duality: "Although the [were] subjunctive seems to be disappearing from the speech of many, its proper use is still a mark of the educated speaker". Thanks again. Kudos!

Comment: "its proper use is still a mark of the educated speaker" this is true.